# How do you triangulate an arbitrary polygon?

Tags: android, rendering, opengl-es, triangulation

I need to triangulate a polygon for rendering in OpenGL ES on Android (no GLU triangulation available).

Is there an already known algorithm for polygon triangulation?  The polygon can be convex or concave (with no holes).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several algorithms out there. One of the most commonly used algorithm is the [ear clipping algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation#Ear_clipping_method). Here's a [page](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~godfried/teaching/cg-projects/97/Ian/cutting_ears.html) with some more detail about this triangulation algorithm.

Comment: Here is the demo of ear clipping http://polyk.ivank.net/?p=demos&d=triangulate

Answer (score 1):

There are some algorithms and implementation of polygon triangulation on these books:

- Computational Geometry: Algorithms and Applications. Chapter 3: Polygon Triangulation.
- Computational Geometry in C. Chapter 1: Polygon Triangulation.